# Installing Ubuntu - Can't see my HDD

Tags: hard-drive, hp, fdisk

I was having some troubles with my HP Pavilion recently, I've tried to re-install Windows from CD, but Windows crashes at the partitions step in the installation. So, I burned Ubuntu on a USB and tried it on.

When I boot from USB, it shows an error multiple time:

> ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=16)

still, UBUNTU does boot from USB and here I am on the installation step, I try Install Ubuntu, then when I get to the part when I choose the partitions, there's only my USB flash that shows up, if I click on the '+' to add another partition, the installer crashs and It takes me to Live Ubuntu.

Here's what `fdisk -l` gives me :

[image: fdisk -l]

As you can see, there's no HDD there, anyone can help me please ? I can give additional infos if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: If both the Windows and Ubuntu installers crash at the same step (partitioning), your HDD may be broken.

Comment: Anyway to make sure ? I'm not an expert, but I thought that since the computer does start up and I can use Live Ubuntu, it means that the hdd is probably okay and it's probably a software rather than hardware issue.